# How to return an array of strings from a function in a COM module?

Tags: c++, com

My function body is as below

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyCustomAddin::getArray(SAFEARRAY** pArray)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

    try {
        CComSafeArray<BSTR> sa(3);

        // 'v' is a std::vector<std::wstring>
        std::vector<std::string> v;
        v.push_back("string1"); v.push_back("string2"); v.push_back("string3");
        for (LONG i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            CComBSTR bstr = ToBstr(v[i]);
            HRESULT hr = sa.SetAt(i, bstr.Detach(), FALSE);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                AtlThrow(hr);
            }
        }

        *pArray= sa.Detach();
    }
    catch (const CAtlException& e)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Exception"));
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

And I called this function from another COM module as:

```
SAFEARRAY** arr;
pMyCUstomAddinObj->getArray(arr);
```

I am getting access violation exception at

```
*pArray= sa.Detach();
```

How to get the array and traverse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SAFEARRAY** arr;
pMyCUstomAddinObj->getArray(arr);
```

With this initialization `pArray` points to garbage, thus `*pArray = ...` is an error. Perhaps you meant to write:

```
SAFEARRAY* arr;
pMyCUstomAddinObj->getArray(&arr);
```